# Formato general me cambia a fecha en Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo en Excel la necesidad de escribir texto de la siguiente forma:
1-12, 11-4, 11-15

Por ejemplo 1-12 me da 12-Jan, 11-4 me da 4-Nov, 11-15 me da 15-Nov

Tengo definido el formato General en las celdas pero al escribir de esa forma excel me lo cambia automaticamente a fecha, como puedo mantener el formato tal cual se escribe en Excel?

DS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos formas de resolver el problema del "autoformato" de fechas que aplica Excel:

1. Al ingresar el texto, agregar un espacio al principio, por ejemplo `<espacio>1-12`, o incluso puedes usar una comilla simple: `'1-12`
2. Aplicar previamente a la columna un formato de Texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me va bien con lo que me recomendaron, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca una comilla sencilla (') antes del texto, ejemplo: '1-12 de esta forma, le estás diciendo a Excel que trate el valor como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Existe otra forma mas, y es creando tu formato personalizado como te muestro en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde las `#` representaria un número y entre comillas dobles va tu separador también podrias usar de la suiguiente manera `00"-"00` y de resultado te arrojaria 01-12 
recuerda que cada `#` o `0` representa un espacio de numero o carácter

Comment: Gracias probado tambien e igual funciona
@Michael Torrez